# Struts2 Action Class with JSON result

Tags: java, json, struts2

I Have some action classes that return JSON results for my Ajax call,

```
<action name="sampleAction" class="com.sample.SampleAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultSecurityStack" />
    <result name="success" type="json">
        <param name="noCache">true</param>
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="root">result</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Is it possible to prevent users from accessing that action directly when typed in the url? Thank you so much!

Comment: Try to take a look at this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/actions/struts-2-redirect-action.shtml)

Comment: Yes, don't define it like action.

Comment: Why would you even want that ? :| BTW actions are mapped to URLs, so...